# Use of typecasting in pointer to an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
int s[4][2] = {1234,56,1212,33,1434,80,1312,78} ;   
int (*p)[2], i, j;    
int *pint;      
for(i=0;i<=3;i++)      
{
    p = s[i];    
    pint = (int*) p;    
    for(j=0;j<=1;j++) 
    {
        printf("%d ",*(pint+j));   
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Here, p is a pointer to an array of 2 integers and p contains the address of the ith 1-D array. But why are we typecasting p to pint? And using pint for the rest of our program. Why can't we use p only instead of pint?

Also, I tried taking p instead of pint, but then it is printing address of 1-D array instead of elements. Why?

Comment: `p = s[i];` is undefined, the types don't match. Same goes for `pint = (int*) p; `.

Comment: Why is p undefined. The statement int (*p)[2] specifies that p is a pointer to an array of 2 integers.This is how we define pointers (like *p).

Comment: The declaration of `p` isn't what he was talking about. He's talking about the *assignment*. If that were `p = s+i;` (or `p = &s[i];`) it would be ok. Your compiler should have complained about "`int (*)[2]` incompatible with `int[2]`" as you have it.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings.

Comment: It is showing the warning "assignment from incompatible pointer type".
p is also a pointer(to an array) and pint is also a pointer (to an integer), both contain address, then why p=s[i] gives me the output of printf as address and after doing pint = (int*)p, i get the output as elements of an array.
Explain the difference please.

Comment: What exactly is the type of p?

Comment: @NamanSharma Its in the compiler warning. `p` has type `int (*)[2]`. `s[i]` has type `int*`. Both are incompatible as seen in the warning.

Comment: Okay.Now i am slightly getting this @CoolGuy. int (*)[2] and int * are different, i agree. But does it matter? I mean how and why taking p instead shows addresses as output of printf

Comment: @NamanSharma it matters *tremendously*, particulary when performing [*pointer arithmetic*](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointer_arithmetic.htm), which, whether you realize it or not, the array subscript operator `[]` does for you.

Comment: Okay. And i got your point.

Comment: One more thing. Someone has answered here that instead of doing pint = int*p, we can do pint =*p,but i don't think they both are same. I mean by doing pint = int*p, we are converting one type to another but if we do pint=*p, it assigns the value at address conatined in p to pint. They both can't be same. However, the output is the same. explain

Comment: When you do weird things, weird things will happen. It is best not to do weird stuff. `p = s[i];` should've been an error, not a warning. But C is loosely typed meaning that it permits you to do many weird stuff. In short, don't ignore compiler warnings. Try to do stuff in the right way.

Answer (score 2):

For starters it would be more correctly to write

```
pint = *p;
```

instead of

```
pint = (int*) p;
```

And this expression statement

```
p = s[i];
```

is also wrong.  s[i] has type `int[2]` that used in expressions is implicitly converted to an object of type `int *`. While the left side operand has type `int ( * )[2]`. So there is an attempt to assign a pointer of type `int( * )[2]` with an expression of type `int *`. However the types are incompatible.

You have to write either

```
p = &s[i];
```

or

```
p = s + i;
```

Of course there is no need to introduce a new pointer that to output elements of the array. However using an additional pointer you can simplify constructions.

Without introducing a new pointer the loop could look like

```
for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++ )      
{
    p = s + i;    

    for ( j = 0; j < 2; j++ ) 
    {
        printf( "%d ", *( *p + j ) );   
    }

    printf( "\n" );
}
```

This quote from the C Standard will be helpful (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
>   operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
>   expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
>   expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
>   element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object
>   has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

Thus array `s` having type `int[4][2]` used in expressions except as an operand of the `sizeof` or `&` operations is converted to pointer to its first element of type `int ( * )[2]`

If to apply operator `*` to the pointer the type of the result object will be `int[2]` that is an array. Again in expressions it in turn is converted to pointer to its first element of type `int *`.

So expression `*p` has type `int *`. If it would be used in the `sizeof` operator then it had type `int[2]`.

Comment: I am now more confused. When we do (int*)p, we are converting it to type int*. But when we do pint =*p, then it means the value stored in address contained in p is assigned to pint. Aren't they both different ?

Comment: @NamanSharma p is a pointer of type int( * )[2]. *p is array of type int[2]. In expressions arrays are converted to pointers to their first elements. so int[2] is con verted to int *. Thus you can write pint = *p;

Comment: I am not exactly getting you. Can you refer me some source from where i can study this pointer part. I am a beginner in this.

Comment: @NamanSharma  I can not advice anything because I do not read books on C.  See also ny updated post.

Answer (score -2):

#### One Dimension arrays:

```
int a[2] ;
```

is equiavalent to:

```
int *a ;
a = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
```

#### Two Dimension arrays:

```
int a[4][2] ;
```

is equivalent to :

```
int **a ;
a = malloc(sizeof(int *)*4);
for ( i = 0 ; i < 2 ; ++i){
*(a+i) = malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
}
```

#### How can it relate to your example:

```
int (*p)[2];
```

type of p : int **

## EDIT:This is wrong

## p is of type (*)[2]

```
int s[4][2] ;
```

type of s : int **

## EDIT:s is type of (*)[2] not **

type of s[i] : int *
type of s[i][j] : int

Credit goes to the commentators, thanks.

Comment: Aside from the whole dynamic memory alllocation stuff that has nothing to do with arrays: As arrays decay to pointers in many contexts, you can treat a 2d array variable almost as a pointer to pointer, but they are not of the same type. In particular, the array size is part of the type and there aren't any actual pointers stored in a 2D-Array (contrary to your dynamically alllocated array of pointers to integer). Oh, and your loop body has a bug (should probably be `a[i] =...`)

Comment: MikeMB is right. Automatic memory allocation and dynamic memory allocation are not the same. Also, "_type of p : int **_" is wrong. `p` has type `int (*)[2]`. The same goes for `s`. Its type is `int (*)[2]`, not `int**`. `int**` and `int (*)[2]` are different. I think that you need to read up on pointers to arrays. In other words, `int (*p)[2]` and `int *p[2]` are not the same. The former is a pointer to a `int[2]`, an array of `int` of size 2 while the latter is an array of pointers to `int`s of size 2.

Comment: well thank you, @MikeMB in the for loop that was a typo, as for the types I thought that arrays were treated behind the scenes as pointers but clearly i am mistaken. @ Cool Guy thanks for making that clear enough. =)